# disable controls in code behind of asp net using for each loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private void DisableControl(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control childControl in divPanelAdd.Controls)
        {
        var textbox = control as TextBox;
        if (textbox != null || textbox == null)
            textbox.Enabled= false;
        var dropDownList = control as DropDownList;
        if (dropDownList != null || dropDownList == null)
            dropDownList.Enabled = false;
            DisableControl(childControl);
        }
    }
```

I'm using for each loop to enable or disable of "divPanelAdd" div but it shows nullexception error.help me to solve this.

Comment: perhaps cos you're using "var textbox=control" not childcontrol? where are you calling this from?

Comment: Your `if` conditions are always true!

Comment: it would fail because textbox == null then textbox.enabled=false so you have a null item and you're setting something on it

Comment: `if (textbox != null || textbox == null)` and `if (dropDownList != null || dropDownList == null)` will always be true (the two conditions in each If are opposites). This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private void DisableControl() {
        foreach (Control childControl in divPanelAdd.Controls) {
            if (childControl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)  || childControl.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList)) 
                ((WebControl)childControl).Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SomeEventHandler(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisableControl(divPanelAdd)
}

// Disable textboxes and dropdowns (recusively) under parent.
private void DisableControl(Control parent)
{
        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
        {
            var textbox = child as TextBox;
            if (textbox != null)
            {
                textbox.Enabled = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                var dropDownList = child as DropDownList;
                if (dropDownList != null)
                {
                    dropDownList.Enabled = false;
                    DisableControl(dropDownList);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

You did intend for this to be recursive?   If so the for shouldn't the for loop refer to the control passed in not divPanel.  divPanel add can be the first parent passed in from somewhere else.